# how to fix the navbar dropdown in mobile browser?

Tags: php, html

i watch tutorial on how to make a navbar responsive the `dropdown` in computer browser is ok but the dropdown in mobile version doesn't work.

**HTML and CSS code** of navbar is as follows;

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;

}

header {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.logo {
    color: #069370;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
    float: right;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    margin padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li.sub-menu:before {
    content: '\f0d7';
    font-family: fontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #262626;
    right: 5px;
    top: 6px;
}


nav ul li.active.sub-menu:before {
    content: '\f0d8';
}

nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    display: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

nav ul li.active ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 210px;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #262626;
}

nav ul li a.active,
nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #069370;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.5s;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    header {
        margin: 20px;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 778px) {
    .menu-toggle {
        display: block;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 10px;
        float: right;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #069370;
    }

    .menu-toggle:before {
        content: '\f0c9';
        font-family: fontAwesome;
        line-height: 40px;
    }

    nav {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu-toggle.active:before {
        content: '\f00d';
    }

    nav.active {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    nav.active ul {
        display: block;
    }

    nav.active ul li a {
        margin: 0;
    }

    nav ul li.active ul {
        position: relative;
        background: #069370;

    }

    nav ul li ul li {

        width: 100%;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo">CMS</a>
        <div class="menu-toggle"></div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#" class="active">Dashboard</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                                <span>Analytics</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="appointment_request.php"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>
                                <span>Appointment Request</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Admin</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="users_management.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                <span>Users Management</span></a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="PHP/action_logout.php">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                                <span class="title">Logout</span>
                            </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Patients</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="patient_information.php"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>
                                <span>Patient Information</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="patient_record.php"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>
                                <span>Patient Records</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Medicines</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="medicine_information.php"><i class="fa fa-medkit"></i>
                                <span>Medicine Information</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="added_stock.php"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                <span>Added Stocks</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="deducted_stock.php"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                <span>Deducted Stocks</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Appointments</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="appointment_info.php"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                <span>Appointment Information</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
        $('.menu-toggle').toggleClass('active')
        $('nav').toggleClass('active')
    })
        $('ul li').click(function(){
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        })
    })
```

when i run the code in mobile version the dropdown doesn't align according to its perspective position , i dont know whats wrong or I'm missing something

Comment: 1. Replace the PHP tag with CSS. 2. Take the [tour] and read the [ask] guide.

Comment: Dropdown is even not working on browser for me

Comment: sorry i dont know how but please help me guys

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown works fine on my phone.
Mayby your brouwser dosn't support it 
Try to update your google chrome on you're phone.

Comment: im testing it on my pc

Comment: it show the dropdown but even though i dont click the dropdown it still showing the items